# Replacing missing data in a categorical variable in R

Tags: r, function, na

I am not sure how I can write a function to replace NA data in a series of categorical vectors.

Consider the following: I have a categorical vector which contains NA data and I want to replace the NA data according to the proportion of the existing data.

For example,

```
a<-factor(c("yes","no","no","yes","yes","yes","no","yes","yes","yes","yes","yes",NA, NA))
```

I wrote the following code:

```
a[is.na(a)]<-sample(c("yes","no"),sum(is.na(a)),replace=TRUE,
prob=c(sum(na.omit(a=="yes"))/sum(!is.na(a)),sum(na.omit(a=="no"))/sum(!is.na(a)))) 

## replace NA with yes or no according to the proportion of yes/no in the non-NA data
```

The above code works fine but now I have a dataframe which contains many categorical variables.
For example:

```
a<-c("yes","no","no","yes","yes","yes","no","yes","yes","yes","yes","yes",NA, NA)
b<-c("red","blue","white","red","blue","red","blue","red","blue","red","blue",NA,NA,NA)
c<-c(1,3,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,NA,NA)

a<-as.factor(a)   ## ensure the vectors are treated as categorical variable
b<-as.factor(b)
c<-as.factor(c)

df<-data.frame(a=a,b=b,c=c)
```

I am struggling in writing a function that would allow me to replace NA data in all categorical variables in such dataframe.   Please note that each variable may have more than two categories.

Comment: In `b` and `c` columns, how do you want the `prob`

Comment: so b would be `prob=c(sum(na.omit(b=="red"))/sum(!is.na(a)),sum(na.omit(b=="blue"))/sum(!is.na(a)),sum(na.omit(b=="white"))/sum(!is.na(a)))`  and c would be `prob=c(sum(na.omit(c==1))/sum(!is.na(a)),sum(na.omit(c==2))/sum(!is.na(a)),sum(na.omit(c==3))/sum(!is.na(a)))`

Comment: Why do you have `is.na(a)` for calculation of prob in `b` column?

Comment: so b would be `prob=c(sum(na.omit(b=="red"))/sum(!is.na(b)),sum(na.omit(b=="blue"))/sum(!is.na‌​(b)),sum(na.omit(b=="white"))/sum(!is.na(b)))` and c would be `prob=c(sum(na.omit(c==1))/sum(!is.na(c)),sum(na.omit(c==2))/sum(!is.na(c)),sum(‌​na.omit(c==3))/sum(!is.na(c)))`

Comment: Which would be equal to the `prob` function by David Arenburg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create some helper function and do the following

```
helperFunc <- function(x){
  sample(levels(x), sum(is.na(x)), replace = TRUE,
         prob = as.numeric(table(x))/sum(!is.na(x)))   
}

df[sapply(df, is.na)]  <- unlist(sapply(df, helperFunc))
```

Test for some random seed (for example, 123)

```
set.seed(123)
df[sapply(df, is.na)]  <- unlist(sapply(df, helperFunc))
df
#      a     b c
# 1  yes   red 1
# 2   no  blue 3
# 3   no white 2
# 4  yes   red 1
# 5  yes  blue 2
# 6  yes   red 3
# 7   no  blue 1
# 8  yes   red 2
# 9  yes  blue 3
# 10 yes   red 1
# 11 yes  blue 2
# 12 yes   red 3
# 13 yes  blue 2
# 14  no white 3
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Could you explain what the helper function is doing?  I am not sure I understand it completely.

Comment: The helper function is doing exactly the same thing that your original code was doing. `as.numeric(table(x))` is just the frequencies of all the unique values in `x` and I divide it by `sum(!is.na(x))` which is the length of `x` without `NA`s. This way a vector of probabilities is created

Comment: This may be a very silly question - but why when you call the helper function in the sapply, you don't need `helperFunc(df)`?

Comment: Because this is how `sapply` syntax works (or all the `apply` family). You give it a data set and it parses each column to the specified function.